# Formula needed: copy a cell while removing text before and after an item

Tags: excel-formula

Need to copy "AAAA-BBBB-" while removing the specific text string before "AAAA-BBBB-", and removing everyting after the 2nd dash.  "AAAA" and "BBBB" represent text strings that are variable in characters and number of characters.

Cell to copy:
"specific text string here AAAA-BBBB-XXXX variable text string after"

Result:
AAAA-BBBB-

[image: example image linked]

Comment: Just a thought, but if you are looking to strim out a particular format, perhaps a Regular Expression could be what you are looking for, these can be used in VBA functions if you must use Excel [Example](https://regex101.com/r/m1cAWH/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","}}}",2))),"Specific Text String Here","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Let's say that the source text is in cell A1 and you want the result in cell B1.
- Since you did not explain what you *actually* want to do, I will assume that you want to extract whatever follows the string `specific text string here` (note the blank at the end) up to and including the second dash.
- We will use an auxiliary column; let's say that column G is the auxiliary column. Put in G1 the formula `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN("specific text string here "))`. This will extract everything that follows `specific text string here` in the value of A1.
- In B1 put the formula `=LEFT(G1,FIND("-",G1)+FIND("-",RIGHT(G1,LEN(G1)-FIND("-",G1))))`. This will extract from G1 the text up to and including the second dash.

[image: Screenshot showing three rows in an Excel worksheet]

Comment: Thank you.  This scenario added the string on the left and I didn't find anything that would help me.  I appreciate your helpfulness, and I do my best to try and present things appropriately - but I'm admittedly lacking in expertise.

Comment: I apologize, but I actually need to have AAAA-BBBB-XXXX in my result.  Your formula worked great, but I was in error.  I can add that the variable text string to the right of XXXX consistently begins with " assignment", followed by variable text.  Can you help me with this.  I've tried manipulating the formula you gave me (B1), but I've failed.

Comment: @KennyJ: Since this is a new problem you should make a new question. In general it is considered better if answers answer the question as asked, so that future readers, who may come this page from a search engine, are not confused.